# Less Categories than Series on Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, categories, series

When I have less Categories than Series on my highcharts, the categories array autofills itselft with the index of every item from the series.

I.E:

```
series = [10,30,54,20,30,40,50,60,07,80,30,20]
categories = [125,250,500]
```

but when I plot the graph this is what I get:

series     = [10,30,54,20,30,40,50,60,07,80,30,20]
categories = [125,250,500,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

I dont want the 4, 5, 6 ... categories to be shown, I just need the ones specified in the categories array, so each category will have more than one single point.

Heres te JSFiddle of an example that happens something like the problem that i'm having.

http://jsfiddle.net/pc4na4fk/

EDIT:
:

[This is the type of graph that I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oreCe.jpg)

Comment: I would question your data source if it is returning more than you want. This seems to be a bad idea in that you could have cases where you dont have data for cat1 or cat2 but you have data for cat3. It is best to sync your data source so that your value and categories are linked correctly.

Comment: so are you saying that you only want the first 3 data points plot since you only have 3 categories?

Comment: I need every data point ploted, but they must fit those 3 categories without expanding the categories array from [125,250,500] to [125,250,500,3,4,5,...]

Answer (score 1):

I could solve it this way:

If I want the first category to be filled, I need to set the x property on the series object from 0.0 to 0.999.. range, and the second category 1.0  to 1.999 range and etc..

here's the JSFiddle that show's how I made it work:

```
 data: [[0,29.9],[0.1,39.9],[0.2,19.9],[0.3,25.9],[0.4,13.9],[1,55.9],[1.1,22.9],[1.2,23.9],[1.3,43.9],[2.1,26.9],[2.2,13.9],[2.3,19.9],[2.4,10.9]]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p4fokmw3/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many values will be in your `categories` array before you define your chart options, you can set the `max` attribute in your x-axis to limit how many items are shown on that axis.

The value of `max` should be the total number of items in the `categories` array, minus 1. So, three items = `max: 2`; two items = `max: 1`; etc.:

```
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['125', '250', '500'], max: 2
    },
```

Here's an updated version of your fiddle with this fix: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/pc4na4fk/2/

I hope this is helpful for you!

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I meant, I still need ALL the points from plot data series to fit the i.e 3 categories defined before.

For each series, i need to have 1+ points, so what I need is to 'unattach' (1 [series point] to 1[ category]) and have something like  1 or more series point for each category.

Comment: You're going to have the match some of the data points to each category. There may be another way to think of this; give me some time and I can think up an alternative solution.

Comment: I have even tought about repeating the categories values so there's always the same length for both arrays, but I think that will ruin the chart.

Comment: http://de.academic.ru/pictures/dewiki/66/Bekesy-3.jpg this is the type of chart that I need

Comment: Oh! What you want to do is set intervals. In a categories array, you'd need to set a bunch of values and then show every second, third, etc. one.

Comment: I didn't get how to do it :S There's a way to specify a integer value category so that I can add the "xAxis" on every series point when plotting? I thik this way should work

Comment: I think I got what I need to do, when populating the series array, I need to set the X property, and if I want to add more than 1 point to the same category, I must add X = 1.1 , X= 1.2 .. etc and if I want to go to the next category I just need to increment the integer value like X=2.0, X=2.1 ...
I'ill test it and report here

Comment: Would your x-axis values ever be a range of numbers, say from 0 to 100? If so, you could set a max, a min, and a tick interval to get the effect you want.

Comment: My x-axis is a range of frequencies, therefore string,  i could solve it the way i commented above, if I want the first category to be filled, i need to set the x 0.0 to 0.999.. range, and the second category 1.0  to 1.999 range

thanks for the help !!

Comment: Of course! I'm glad to have helped you along the way to your solution.